# ReDim Preserve to a multi-dimensional array in VB6

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array, vb6, dynamic-arrays, preserve

I'm using VB6 and I need to do a `ReDim Preserve` to a Multi-Dimensional Array:

```
 Dim n, m As Integer
    n = 1
    m = 0
    Dim arrCity() As String
    ReDim arrCity(n, m)
    
    n = n + 1
    m = m + 1
    ReDim Preserve arrCity(n, m)
```

Whenever I do it as I have written it, I get the following error:

> runtime error 9: subscript out of range

Because I can only change the last array dimension, well in my task I have to change the whole array (2 dimensions in my example) !

Is there any workaround or another solution for this?

Answer (score 9):

As you correctly point out, one can `ReDim Preserve` only the last dimension of an array ([ReDim Statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa266231.aspx) on MSDN):

> If you use the Preserve keyword, you can resize only the last array
>   dimension and you can't change the number of dimensions at all. For
>   example, if your array has only one dimension, you can resize that
>   dimension because it is the last and only dimension. However, if your
>   array has two or more dimensions, you can change the size of only the
>   last dimension and still preserve the contents of the array

Hence, the first issue to decide is whether 2-dimensional array is the best data structure for the job. Maybe, 1-dimensional array is a better fit as you need to do `ReDim Preserve`?

Another way is to use jagged array as per [Pieter Geerkens's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16369934/262403). There is no direct support for jagged arrays in VB6. One way to code "array of arrays" in VB6 is to declare an array of `Variant` and make each element an array of desired type (`String` in your case). Demo code is below.

Yet another option is to implement `Preserve` part on your own. For that you'll need to create a copy of data to be preserved and then fill redimensioned array with it.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub TestMatrixResize()
    Const MAX_D1 As Long = 2
    Const MAX_D2 As Long = 3

    Dim arr() As Variant
    InitMatrix arr, MAX_D1, MAX_D2
    PrintMatrix "Original array:", arr

    ResizeMatrix arr, MAX_D1 + 1, MAX_D2 + 1
    PrintMatrix "Resized array:", arr
End Sub

Private Sub InitMatrix(a() As Variant, n As Long, m As Long)
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim StringArray() As String

    ReDim a(n)
    For i = 0 To n
        ReDim StringArray(m)
        For j = 0 To m
            StringArray(j) = i * (m + 1) + j
        Next j
        a(i) = StringArray
    Next i
End Sub

Private Sub PrintMatrix(heading As String, a() As Variant)
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim s As String

    Debug.Print heading
    For i = 0 To UBound(a)
        s = ""
        For j = 0 To UBound(a(i))
            s = s & a(i)(j) & "; "
        Next j
        Debug.Print s
    Next i
End Sub

Private Sub ResizeMatrix(a() As Variant, n As Long, m As Long)
    Dim i As Long
    Dim StringArray() As String

    ReDim Preserve a(n)
    For i = 0 To n - 1
        StringArray = a(i)
        ReDim Preserve StringArray(m)
        a(i) = StringArray
    Next i
    ReDim StringArray(m)
    a(n) = StringArray
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm afraid if there will be a "type mismatch" error in the line "StringArray=a(i)" in the function ResizeMatrix. If i goes past the range of the old matrix, a(i) is of type Variant/Empty. Can it be passed to something of the type String()?

Comment: *"the first issue to decide is whether 2-dimensional array is the best data structure for the job."* . Some functions require a 2D array, such as https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.shapes.addcurve . So how can we generate the array if the number of elements are only known at run time is a valid question.

Answer (score 6):

Since VB6 is very similar to VBA, I think I might have a solution which does not require this much code to `ReDim` a 2-dimensional array - using `Transpose`, if you are working in Excel.

**The solution (Excel VBA):**

```
Dim n, m As Integer
n = 2
m = 1
Dim arrCity() As Variant
ReDim arrCity(1 To n, 1 To m)

m = m + 1
ReDim Preserve arrCity(1 To n, 1 To m)
arrCity = Application.Transpose(arrCity)
n = n + 1
ReDim Preserve arrCity(1 To m, 1 To n)
arrCity = Application.Transpose(arrCity)
```

What is different from OP's question: the lower bound of `arrCity` array is not 0, but 1. This is in order to let `Application.Transpose` do it's job.

Note that `Transpose` is a method of the Excel `Application` object (which in actuality is a shortcut to `Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose`). And in VBA, one must take care when using `Transpose` as it has two significant limitations: If the array has more than 65536 elements, it will fail. If ANY element's length exceed 256 characters, it will fail. If neither of these is an issue, then Transpose will nicely convert the rank of an array form 1D to 2D or vice-versa.

Unfortunately there is nothing like 'Transpose' build into VB6.

Comment: No. Transpose is a method of the Excel Application object (which in actuality is a shortcut to Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose). There is nothing like that in VB6. And in VBA, one must take care when using Transpose as it has two significant limitations. If the array has more than 65536 elements, it will fail. In ANY element's length exceed 256 characters, it will fail. If neither of these is an issue, then Transpose will nicely convert the rank of an array form 1D to 2D or vice-versa.

Comment: Can I ask you where/how did you learn that Application.Transpose is a *shortcut* to Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose ?

Answer (score 3):

In regards to this:

> "in my task I have to change the whole array (2 dimensions"

Just use a "jagged" array (ie an array of arrays of values). Then you can change the dimensions as you wish. You can have a 1-D array of variants, and the variants can contain arrays.

A bit more work perhaps, but a solution.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't tested every single one of these answers but you don't need to use complicated functions to accomplish this. It's so much easier than that! My code below will work in any office VBA application (Word, Access, Excel, Outlook, etc.) and is very simple. Hope this helps:

```
''Dimension 2 Arrays
Dim InnerArray(1 To 3) As Variant ''The inner is for storing each column value of the current row
Dim OuterArray() As Variant ''The outer is for storing each row in
Dim i As Byte

    i = 1
    Do While i <= 5

        ''Enlarging our outer array to store a/another row
        ReDim Preserve OuterArray(1 To i)

        ''Loading the current row column data in
        InnerArray(1) = "My First Column in Row " & i
        InnerArray(2) = "My Second Column in Row " & i
        InnerArray(3) = "My Third Column in Row " & i

        ''Loading the entire row into our array
        OuterArray(i) = InnerArray

        i = i + 1
    Loop

    ''Example print out of the array to the Intermediate Window
    Debug.Print OuterArray(1)(1)
    Debug.Print OuterArray(1)(2)
    Debug.Print OuterArray(2)(1)
    Debug.Print OuterArray(2)(2)
```

Answer (score 2):

I know this is a bit old but I think there might be a much simpler solution that requires no additional coding:

Instead of transposing, redimming and transposing again, and if we talk about a two dimensional array, why not just store the values transposed to begin with. In that case redim preserve actually increases the right (second) dimension from the start. Or in other words, to visualise it, why not store in two rows instead of two columns if only the nr of columns can be increased with redim preserve.

the indexes would than be 00-01, 01-11, 02-12, 03-13, 04-14, 05-15 ... 0 25-1 25 etcetera instead of 00-01, 10-11, 20-21, 30-31, 40-41 etcetera.

As long as there is only one dimension that needs to be redimmed-preserved the approach would still work: just put that dimension last.

As only the second (or last) dimension can be preserved while redimming, one could maybe argue that this is how arrays are supposed to be used to begin with.
I have not seen this solution anywhere so maybe I'm overlooking something?

(Posted earlier on similar question regarding two dimensions, extended answer here for more dimensions)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a user defined type containing an array of strings which will be the inner array. Then you can use an array of this user defined type as your outer array.

Have a look at the following test project:

```
'1 form with:
'  command button: name=Command1
'  command button: name=Command2
Option Explicit

Private Type MyArray
  strInner() As String
End Type

Private mudtOuter() As MyArray

Private Sub Command1_Click()
  'change the dimensens of the outer array, and fill the extra elements with "1"
  Dim intOuter As Integer
  Dim intInner As Integer
  Dim intOldOuter As Integer
  intOldOuter = UBound(mudtOuter)
  ReDim Preserve mudtOuter(intOldOuter + 2) As MyArray
  For intOuter = intOldOuter + 1 To UBound(mudtOuter)
    ReDim mudtOuter(intOuter).strInner(intOuter) As String
    For intInner = 0 To UBound(mudtOuter(intOuter).strInner)
      mudtOuter(intOuter).strInner(intInner) = "1"
    Next intInner
  Next intOuter
End Sub

Private Sub Command2_Click()
  'change the dimensions of the middle inner array, and fill the extra elements with "2"
  Dim intOuter As Integer
  Dim intInner As Integer
  Dim intOldInner As Integer
  intOuter = UBound(mudtOuter) / 2
  intOldInner = UBound(mudtOuter(intOuter).strInner)
  ReDim Preserve mudtOuter(intOuter).strInner(intOldInner + 5) As String
  For intInner = intOldInner + 1 To UBound(mudtOuter(intOuter).strInner)
    mudtOuter(intOuter).strInner(intInner) = "2"
  Next intInner
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Click()
  'clear the form and print the outer,inner arrays
  Dim intOuter As Integer
  Dim intInner As Integer
  Cls
  For intOuter = 0 To UBound(mudtOuter)
    For intInner = 0 To UBound(mudtOuter(intOuter).strInner)
      Print CStr(intOuter) & "," & CStr(intInner) & " = " & mudtOuter(intOuter).strInner(intInner)
    Next intInner
    Print "" 'add an empty line between the outer array elements
  Next intOuter
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Load()
  'init the arrays
  Dim intOuter As Integer
  Dim intInner As Integer
  ReDim mudtOuter(5) As MyArray
  For intOuter = 0 To UBound(mudtOuter)
    ReDim mudtOuter(intOuter).strInner(intOuter) As String
    For intInner = 0 To UBound(mudtOuter(intOuter).strInner)
      mudtOuter(intOuter).strInner(intInner) = CStr((intOuter + 1) * (intInner + 1))
    Next intInner
  Next intOuter
  WindowState = vbMaximized
End Sub
```

Run the project, and click on the form to display the contents of the arrays.

Click on Command1 to enlarge the outer array, and click on the form again to show the results.

Click on Command2 to enlarge an inner array, and click on the form again to show the results.

Be careful though: when you redim the outer array, you also have to redim the inner arrays for all the new elements of the outer array

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled across this question while hitting this road block myself. I ended up writing a piece of code real quick to handle this `ReDim Preserve` on a new sized array (first or last dimension). Maybe it will help others who face the same issue.

So for the usage, lets say you have your array originally set as  `MyArray(3,5)`, and you want to make the dimensions (first too!) larger, lets just say to `MyArray(10,20)`. You would be used to doing something like this right?

```
 ReDim Preserve MyArray(10,20) '<-- Returns Error
```

But unfortunately that returns an error because you tried to change the size of the first dimension.  So with my function, you would just do something like this instead:

```
 MyArray = ReDimPreserve(MyArray,10,20)
```

Now the array is larger, and the data is preserved. Your `ReDim Preserve` for a Multi-Dimension array is complete. :)

And last but not least, the miraculous function: `ReDimPreserve()`

```
'redim preserve both dimensions for a multidimension array *ONLY
Public Function ReDimPreserve(aArrayToPreserve,nNewFirstUBound,nNewLastUBound)
    ReDimPreserve = False
    'check if its in array first
    If IsArray(aArrayToPreserve) Then       
        'create new array
        ReDim aPreservedArray(nNewFirstUBound,nNewLastUBound)
        'get old lBound/uBound
        nOldFirstUBound = uBound(aArrayToPreserve,1)
        nOldLastUBound = uBound(aArrayToPreserve,2)         
        'loop through first
        For nFirst = lBound(aArrayToPreserve,1) to nNewFirstUBound
            For nLast = lBound(aArrayToPreserve,2) to nNewLastUBound
                'if its in range, then append to new array the same way
                If nOldFirstUBound >= nFirst And nOldLastUBound >= nLast Then
                    aPreservedArray(nFirst,nLast) = aArrayToPreserve(nFirst,nLast)
                End If
            Next
        Next            
        'return the array redimmed
        If IsArray(aPreservedArray) Then ReDimPreserve = aPreservedArray
    End If
End Function
```

I wrote this in like 20 minutes, so there's no guarantees. But if you would like to use or extend it, feel free.  I would've thought that someone would've had some code like this up here already, well apparently not. So here ya go fellow gearheads.

Answer (score 0):

This is more compact and respect the intial first position in array and just use the inital bound to add old value.

```
Public Sub ReDimPreserve(ByRef arr, ByVal size1 As Long, ByVal size2 As Long)
Dim arr2 As Variant
Dim x As Long, y As Long

'Check if it's an array first
If Not IsArray(arr) Then Exit Sub

'create new array with initial start
ReDim arr2(LBound(arr, 1) To size1, LBound(arr, 2) To size2)

'loop through first
For x = LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1)
    For y = LBound(arr, 2) To UBound(arr, 2)
        'if its in range, then append to new array the same way
        arr2(x, y) = arr(x, y)
    Next
Next
'return byref
arr = arr2
End Sub
```

I call this sub with this line to resize the first dimension

```
ReDimPreserve arr2, UBound(arr2, 1) + 1, UBound(arr2, 2)
```

You can add an other test to verify if the initial size is not upper than new array. In my case it's not necessary

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to do this in VBA is to create a function that takes in an array, your new amount of rows, and new amount of columns.

Run the below function to copy in all of the old data back to the array after it has been resized.

```
 function dynamic_preserve(array1, num_rows, num_cols)

        dim array2 as variant

        array2 = array1

        reDim array1(1 to num_rows, 1 to num_cols)

        for i = lbound(array2, 1) to ubound(array2, 2)

               for j = lbound(array2,2) to ubound(array2,2)

                      array1(i,j) = array2(i,j)

               next j

        next i

        dynamic_preserve = array1

end function
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Function Redim2d(ByRef Mtx As Variant, ByVal QtyColumnToAdd As Integer)
    ReDim Preserve Mtx(LBound(Mtx, 1) To UBound(Mtx, 1), LBound(Mtx, 2) To UBound(Mtx, 2) + QtyColumnToAdd)
End Function

'Main Code
sub Main ()
    Call Redim2d(MtxR8Strat, 1)  'Add one column
end sub

'OR
sub main2()
    QtyColumnToAdd = 1 'Add one column
    ReDim Preserve Mtx(LBound(Mtx, 1) To UBound(Mtx, 1), LBound(Mtx, 2) To UBound(Mtx, 2) + QtyColumnToAdd)
end sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If you not want include other function like 'ReDimPreserve' could use temporal matrix for resizing. On based to your code:

```vb
 Dim n As Integer, m As Integer, i as Long, j as Long
 Dim arrTemporal() as Variant

    n = 1
    m = 0
    Dim arrCity() As String
    ReDim arrCity(n, m)

    n = n + 1
    m = m + 1

    'VBA automatically adapts the size of the receiving matrix.
    arrTemporal = arrCity
    ReDim arrCity(n, m)

    'Loop for assign values to arrCity
    For i = 1 To UBound(arrTemporal , 1)
        For j = 1 To UBound(arrTemporal , 2)
            arrCity(i, j) = arrTemporal (i, j)
        Next
    Next
```

If you not declare of type VBA assume that is Variant.

Dim n ***as Integer***, m As Integer