# Debugging VBA code - appending values to array

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to use code of the following form to populate an array of x rows:

```
Dim myarray() As Variant
Dim string1 As String

Dim myarray_ubound As Integer
myarray_ubound = 0

For i = 1 to x

  myarray_ubound = myarray_ubound + 1
  ReDim Preserve myarray(1 To myarray_ubound, 1 To 2)

  myarray(myarray_ubound,1) = i
  myarray(myarray_ubound,2) = string1

Next i
```

However, when I run it it gets stuck after the first loop, telling me that a subscript is out of range. Debugging takes me to the ReDim command.

I used myarray_ubound as an alternative to calling the UBound function many times, but I have tried using this as well and I get the same error.

Can anyone spot what's gone wrong?

Comment: decide if you want a one dimensional array or two

Comment: I want two ... is this not?

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16369217/redim-preserve-to-a-multi-dimensional-array-in-visual-basic-6) can help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa266231.aspx
"If you use the Preserve keyword, you can resize only the last array dimension and you can't change the number of dimensions at all."

Try

```
ReDim Preserve myarray(1 To 2, 1 To myarray_ubound)
```

instead.

Answer (score 3):

you can only redim the last element of the array (not the first), see below. As you know x I would suggest to redim your array with this value from the beginning.

```
Dim myarray() As Variant
Dim string1 As String

Dim myarray_ubound As Integer
myarray_ubound = 0

For i = 1 To 10

  myarray_ubound = myarray_ubound + 1
  ReDim Preserve myarray(1 To 2, 1 To myarray_ubound)

  myarray(1, myarray_ubound) = i
  myarray(2, myarray_ubound) = string1

Next i
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are declaring the variable as a Variant i don't see why you need to re-dim. (maybe related to memory issues, feel free to fill in).

I would suggest:

```
For i = 1 to 10

myArray(1, i-1) = i
myArray(2, i-1) = string1

next i
```

Comment: That's a fair comment: the reason is that this is part of a loop so x varies. Thanks for your help.