# How to work with string()()

Tags: vb.net, preserve

I have a string()() array that it must be redim in for loop.So How can i do this.
A code like this.

```
dim arr as string()()=nothing
dim z as integer=nothing
for i= 1 to 5
  for j=0 to 536
      if j mod i =0 then
           redim preserve arr(z)(i)=i.tostring
           z+=1
      end if
   next
next
```

Comment: it is similar to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16369217/redim-preserve-to-a-multi-dimensional-array-in-visual-basic-6

Comment: in this link n in redim a(n) is given. but in my problem i is not clear.if i is clear, i am not problem.

Comment: I change the my code.now z in not clear.

Comment: How can i dynamically add top-level to jagged array ?

Comment: You can use `Redim Preserve arr(z)`.

Comment: It does not work.

Answer (score 0):

I found that i must redim arr step by step like below:

```
redim arr(z)
redim arr(z)(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good reference on Redim. Do not forget to preserve your values.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w8k3cys2.aspx